# Program works in Pry but nowhere else (Errno::EN0ENT) No such File or directory

Tags: ruby, sitemap

Here is the code I'm working with. Trying to do some cool stuff. At the moment I just want this portion to work.

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'
require 'colorize'
puts "Image sitemap generator".colorize(:blue)
puts "Not compatibile with tiered sitemaps".colorize(:red)
puts "v.0.1".colorize(:blue)
puts "-----------------------------------------------------------------"
puts "Enter the site you'd like an image sitemap for?"
site = gets.chomp
path = "/sitemap.xml"
target = "#{site}#{path}"
sitemap = Nokogiri::HTML(open(target))
links = sitemap.xpath('//url/loc')
links.each do |link|
    puts link
end
```

It doesn't work on my machine and gives the error:

```
imgsm.rb:12:in `initialize': No such file or directory - http://website.com/sitemap.xml (Errno::ENOENT)
    from imgsm.rb:12:in `open'
    from imgsm.rb:12:in `<main>'`
```

However it works perfectly fine in pry and irb. What's happening and how do I fix this? It's incredibly frustrating. I've tried removing Ruby, updating Ruby and going back to a previous version. Nothing has worked at fixing the issue.

Comment: What `open-uri` does is it monkey patches `Kernel.open`, to allow it to open remote files. The error you get indicates that `open` treats your URL as a path to a file on the local file system, in turn indicating that the `open-uri` module was not loaded. If you can figure out why, you can solve this problem.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'll work on troubleshooting, but it might be a bit beyond my skill level. Any ideas on where to start would be awesome. Thanks for your time.

Comment: How are you running the script? Using `ruby imgsm.rb`? Is the code you posted all the code contained in `imgsm.rb`?

Comment: Yes to both questions. I'm using `ruby imgsm.rb` and the code is everything that is contained.

Comment: Could you check that the version of ruby underlying pry is the same as the one you use to run the script? Try

`pry --version` and `ruby --version`

Comment: `Andrews-MacBook-Pro:ruby andrewcorbett$ pry -v
Pry version 0.10.1 on Ruby 2.1.1`